# Cannot achieve a successful sqlite query to display in my text view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to display a string of text in a text view. According to NSLog the database is found but, I cannot retrieve the data from the table. Could someone point out what is wrong with my query? (I may need this explained in very simple terms. I've been sing objective-c for only a few days.)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

 NSString *docsDir;
 NSArray *dirPaths;

 // Get the documents directory
 dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

 // Build the path to the database file
 databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"trivia_game.db"]];
 NSLog(@"Full DB path: %@", databasePath);

 NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
 {
     const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
     NSLog(@"[SQLITE] DB not found");

     } else {
     NSLog(@"[SQLITE] trivia_game.db found");
         }

 const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;

 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &questionsForGame) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
     NSLog(@"[SQLITE] db opened");

     NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT question, answer0, answer1, answer2, answer3 FROM questions"];
     NSLog(@"[SQLITE] string is: %@", querySQL);

     const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];


     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(questionsForGame, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
         NSLog(@"[SQLITE] written!");

         if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
         {
             NSString *textField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
             questHolder.text = textField;
             NSLog(@"[SQLITE] string is: %@",textField);




             [textField release];


         } else {
             questHolder.text = @"query not found";
             NSLog(@"[SQLITE] Unable to open database!");

         }
         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
         sqlite3_close(questionsForGame);

     } else {
         NSLog(@"[SQLITE] Screwed up query!");
         questHolder.text = @"query not found";


     }


 }


 [filemgr release];
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

}

log:

[Session started at 2012-05-28 12:27:19 -0300.]
2012-05-28 12:27:20.547 ans[9374:207] Full DB path: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/0B4C50FB-5A3F-4371-83D6-1A2AF95B9F66/Documents/trivia_game.db

2012-05-28 12:27:20.549 ans[9374:207] [SQLITE] trivia_game.db found

2012-05-28 12:27:20.550 ans[9374:207] [SQLITE] db opened

2012-05-28 12:27:20.551 ans[9374:207] [SQLITE] string is: SELECT question, answer0, answer1, answer2, answer3 FROM questions

2012-05-28 12:27:20.553 ans[9374:207] [SQLITE] Screwed up query!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the SQLite library you're using but I would recommend to switch to Core Data. cf. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html